# Angular - map to returnedEntity in an API response

Tags: angular, api, http, observable

I'm using Angular 8.2 and calling a .NET Core 3.1 API and I'm able to get the call to work and return the data that I need, but the syntax I ended up using looks like it could be simplified, but so far no alternatives that I've tried seem to work.

I'm calling the API this way:

```
getCatsApi(): Observable<any[] | DataServiceError> {        
    console.log("API");       
    let mcats = this._http.get<any[]>( Settings.apiRoot + 'api/Cat/GetCats')
        .pipe(
            catchError(err => this.handleHttpError(err))
        )        
    console.log("Get Cats from API");
    console.log(mcats);
    return mcats;
}
```

This returns a response structure that looks like this:

[image]

The data I want is in the "returnedEntity" property, just below the "responseErrors" property.

I'm able to get at this data in what seems like a messy way:

```
getCats(){
this._dataService.getCatsApi().subscribe(data => {
  for(let j = 0; j < data['returnedEntity']['catList'].length; j++) {
    console.log(data['returnedEntity']['catList'][j]);
    this.catsObj.push(data['returnedEntity']['catList'][j]);
  }
});
```

}

This does work and I receive the data that I need. But it seems like there must be a better way to get the returnedEntity back without explicitly referring to it with array strings. I am using `<any[]>` in the original HTTP call, but if I change that to the `<Category[]>` interface that I created it doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm guessing that I need to use some form of the rxjs .map() function, but so far I haven't found a way to make that work. This makes me wonder if something else is wrong? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either edit the backend to return the `catList` property directly or map the response using RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) before subscribing to it. The loop you're using seems redundant.

If the object signature of the data from backend matches your front-end type `Category`, you could also replace `any[]` with `Category[]`.

Service

```js
getCatsApi(): Observable<Category[] | DataServiceError> {        
  return this._http.get( Settings.apiRoot + 'api/Cat/GetCats').pipe(
    map(response => response['returnedEntity']['catList']),       // <-- map the reponse here to return the `catList` array
    catchError(err => this.handleHttpError(err))
  );
}
```

Controller

```js
getCats(){
  this._dataService.getCatsApi().subscribe(
    data => { this.catsObj = data },
    error => { }
  );
}
```

<sup>Also the name `catsObj` looks misleading given it's an array.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

due of `data['returnedEntity']['catList']` seems that your returnedEntity have an attribute named 'cadList' with an array type.

your `data['returnedEntity']` must have a `T` type,

then you can write something as :

```
this.catsObj = data['returnedEntity']
```

also, share some backend code please